# How to pass a an argument to getByText in react Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Currently I'm doing this

```
getByText(/SomeText/i);
```

But I want to make a function and pass some text as an argument by first storing it in a variable. I tried doing it like this:

```
let x = "/SomeText/i";
getByText(x);
```

or

```
getByText(`/${x}/i`);
```

But none of the options work.

Answer (score 38):

If you have

```
const x = "Some string"
```

To test for `x` using regex,

```
getByText(new RegExp(x, "i"))
```

Comment: Or simply use the RegEx as a variable. `const x = /Some string/i; getByText(x);`

Answer (score 28):

Perhaps you are looking for passing `exact: false`?

```
// Match a substring of Hello World
getByText(container, 'llo Worl', { exact: false }) // substring match
```

You can also pass your own matching custom function.

```
getByText(container, (content, element) => content.startsWith('Hello'))
```

https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/cheatsheet#text-match-options

Comment: I would say `{ exact: false }` is the way to go

Answer (score 4):

I think your issue is your trying to set a RegEx as though it's a string

```
// Doesn't need quotes
let x = /SomeText/i

getByText(x)
```

What you're asking `getByText` to find is literally /SomeText/i, which I imagine your document does not have in it

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO!

I haven't tested this, but it seems getByText needs a regular expression:

```
getByText(/SomeText/i);
```

as an argument and not, as you put here, a string:

```
let x = "/SomeText/i";
```

Does your code work if you create a regex from your string, like this?

```
let x = new RegExp("/SomeText/i");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But the solution doesn't work. I got the following error on console. 
Unable to find an element with the text: /\/SomeText\/i/.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar scenario where I needed a variable:

```
    const x = 'some text';
    getByText(`${x}`);
```

Comment: This is equivalent to `getByText(x)`